# Is the London Pass worth the price?

Tags: tickets, london

We are going to spend 2 days in London in mid-December and we wonder if we should buy the [London Pass](http://www.londonpass.com/) which is £46.00 per day per adult. It is not the first time we have used this kind of pass and have always been satisfied with it in the past. However, this one seems pretty expensive to me. Would I save much money by paying the £184.00 for the two days in London?

Comment: It becomes a question of simple mathematics figure out where you want to go, figure out what the costs are and the savings with London Pass once done the answer will be clearer...

Comment: Hard to tell, how can I know how much activities I have time to do? How can I calculate the price of the public transportation (which is included in a ticket of slightly higher price)?

Comment: London is more expensive than other cities, especially the museums, the london eye etc.. so I think 46£ is not too much

Comment: @Zonata Assume that you will pay a single ride price to get there and back.  So that's your cost on transportation.  As far as activities are concerned that's for you to guesstimate.

Comment: @Dirty-flow Ummmmm.  What if you all you want to do is visit 2 museums covered by the pass and that's it?  It's quite likely the pass will not be worth it, so a full plan is necessary to answer the question.

Comment: @Karlson he should better know what he wants to visit but if he wants >3 museums it's better to buy the pass. It's almost impossible to answer the question without addition information, because the ticket covers many attractions, but we don't know which of them are interesting for him

Comment: @Dirty-flow, most museums are fee in London, at least the standard exhibitions.

Comment: @Dirty-flow; Have you been to museums in London? The majority are completely free.

Comment: Yes, I have been there. And there are also some museums that were very interesting for me(like tower bridge, wimbledon and wembley tours), and they were not free - so it depends of the Interest of the visitor

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given that there are so many free sites in London such as the British Museum, the National Portrait Gallery, the Tate Britain and the Tate Modern (before you even fit in time for sightseeing), I would suggest that £46 is money that could be spent elsewhere.

If you bought passes like that on such a short trip, you would spend more time worrying about what sites on the pass you will fit into your tight schedule and generally getting quite stressed.

I'd suggest you consider all the free things first and factor in time and costs for a visit to one or two sites with an entry fee.

Comment: I agree, and I don't think the travelcard adds much to the deal either. A Zone 1-2 (That's more than a big enough area for a couple of days) travelcard is [£8.40/adult](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tickets/14416.aspx) (£7/adult off-peak/weekends), and if you want increased flexibility, you can get Oyster cards (RFID touch-in, touch-out travel cards that have cheaper rates and are capped at the equivalent travel card each day), for a £5 returnable deposit.

Comment: Thank you, exactly the piece of advice I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

I guess it depends on what you want to see in London, and make sure that your attractions are included. If you just want to do the usual highlights then I would say that it doesn't make sense to buy these passes, especially that some of the attractions listed in top 10 are quite far from London (e.g. Hampton Court) or even completely outside (Windsor). The site suggests some savings if you visit three things every day, but I just can't see how one can reasonably visit Hampton Court, Windsor and something else on one day!

All the major museums are free in London (excluding special exhibitions). You probably want to visit the main churches - Westminster Abbey and St. Paul's Cathedral. They are not cheep, but together cost still less than £46, that's for sure. Insider tip: if you want to get inside for free, just go for one of the services.

For public transport buy prepaid Oyster cards - you pay for every trip, but the amount is capped daily at the appropriate daily ticket rate.